# Is it possible to create a custom form for a list with lookup column through Power Apps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Scenario:

1. Open the list which has a lookup field.
2. Click on 'Customize forms' command under 'Power Apps' in the command bar at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

You can customize the SharePoint list which has lookup columns in it.

Here are the examples of others using lookup columns while customizing list forms:

1. [Create(customize) Form for Sharepoint list (auto population based on lookup)](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Create-customize-Form-for-Sharepoint-list-auto-population-based/m-p/114332)
2. [PowerApps Tip: Setting a SharePoint List Lookup Column](https://sympmarc.com/2018/02/05/powerapps-setting-a-sharepoint-list-lookup-column/)
3. [Customize SharePoint Forms With PowerApps](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/customize-sharepoint-forms-with-powerapps/)

---

**Update**:

If you are not able to customize the list forms using "Customize forms" option in command bar, follow below workaround:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on **Settings** icon and select **List settings**
3. Select **Form settings**
4. Click on **Customize in PowerApps** under **Use a custom form created in PowerApps (requires new list experience)**

[image]

Comment: I have a simple test list. As soon as I add lookup field click on 'Customize forms' does not do anything. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on my tenant today. Even for newly created list with only Title column, I am not able to customize list forms using Power Apps.

Comment: Check my updated answer for workaround to customize forms using Power apps. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: My problem was that Power App was not launched when I clicked on 'Customize forms'. I found that after refreshing the page it started loading. I seems nothing to do with lookup column. Thank you for tackling my issue. I understand that it was vague.

Comment: Yes, same problem for me. But you can customize list forms using 2 ways: 1. Using "Customize forms" from command bar. 2. workaround given in my updated answer. It's always good to know multiple ways to work with (if first option does not work).